# Create dotenv file before build and deploy to dockerhub using GitHub Actions

Tags: linux, docker, github-actions, dotenv

I'm trying to create a dotenv file using the GitHub Secrets before I build my Golang app and before I deploy it to my DockerHub repository.
When I run the Job it actually creates the file but when I run the image in a container a message that .env file is not found is shown.

Here is my .yml file
name: Build and Push Image

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - 'main'

jobs:
  dotenv:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    -
      name: generate dotenv for go
      run: |
        echo DB_USER=${{ secrets.SECRET_USER_DB }} > .env
        echo PASSWORD_DB=${{ secrets.SECRET_PASSWORD_DB }} > .env
        echo HOST_DB=${{ secrets.SECRET_HOST_DB }} > .env
        echo PORT_DB=${{ secrets.SECRET_PORT_DB }} > .env
        echo NAME_DB=${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME_DB }} > .env
  
  docker:
    needs: dotenv
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          repository: dall06/go_api_image
          file: .docker/Dockerfile.prod
          tags: dall06/go_api_image:latest
```

And my Dockerfile is this

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /app

# manage dependencies
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

ENV PORT 8080

RUN go build

CMD [ "./pssword-api-mysql" ]
```

Comment: `> .env` truncates the file each time. Use `>>` for all but the first command, or wrap all the echos into `{ ... }` and redirect just once: `{ echo ...; echo ...; } > .env`

Comment: It stills send the error that the file or directory does not exists

Comment: I made the change of wrapping the echoes in {}

Comment: I ran the image using bash and the file is not in ti

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a .env file in a Ubuntu machine and docker image in another Ubuntu machine, the `needs` keyword makes sure that docker job runs after dotenv job.

What you can do is, remove dotenv job all together and create dotenv file in docker build job itself.

Or, upload the .env using `upload artifacts` action in `dotenv` job and download the artifact using `download artifacts` action in your Docker Build job.

Comment: Also make sure to use `>>` instead of `>`, since `>` puts only last value and empties all other values, whereas `>>` puts values below each other.